# Merging and counting row records (ssrs)

Tags: reporting-services, merge, duplicates, rows, reportbuilder3.0

I need some help in SSRS Report builder 3.0 (Microsofs SQL server 2014). I need to create a CSV data file with address information taking out duplicate rows but sum the quntity of the duplicate rows to know the total quantity.

For example my file looks like: 
[image: Data file before]

What I need is that all rows that are duplicate merge and give a sum of the of the values in the Qty column, when two rows have a qty of 1 new value should be 2. In case one row has qty of 1 and the other a qty of 2, the new gty should become 3. This all has to be done without compromising the file build.

The outcome should look like this:
[image: Data file after]

Is this possible? if yes, what is the best way to do it?

Greetz!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either set up a group based on the columns which contain identical values between the records you want to "merge" and then use the `SUM` function to sum your quantity for each group, or handle it in your DataSet query, like:

```
SELECT Customer_Name,
       Sub_Customer_Name,
       Post_Type,
       Equipment_Size,
       SUM(Qty),
       Trans_Mode,
       Address_1,
       City,
       ST,
       Postal_Code,
       Country,
       PortRampID,
       PortRamp_Name,
       PortRamp_Code,
       Ship_Line_Name,
       AvailableDate,
       ExpiredDate
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY Customer_Name,
         Sub_Customer_Name,
         Post_Type,
         Equipment_Size,
         Trans_Mode,
         Address_1,
         City,
         ST,
         Postal_Code,
         Country,
         PortRampID,
         PortRamp_Name,
         PortRamp_Code,
         Ship_Line_Name,
         AvailableDate,
         ExpiredDate
```